# Take the most recent date and the most remote one and calculate the months between them with .groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, pandas-groupby, jupyter

I'd like to get the number of month in between these dates (between max and minimum date) and keep the same order in the groupby

[image]

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)

Comment: @RyanM you did not fully roll back the edits. Notice that revision 3 deleted the image, making the question entirely different/useless than revision 2.

Comment: @user12986714 my second rollback a few seconds after the first corrected that error.  but thanks for the heads-up in case I hadn't noticed!

Comment: Apart from all that, please post text instead of images so others can easier copy/paste parts of it when answering.

Comment: @scipy Again? Please don't.

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions is to start from a *datesac* - the result
of your grouping (presented in your picture).
I also assume that *ORDER_INST* column of your source DataFrame is of *datetime* type (not a string) and hence just this type has also level 1 of
the MultiIndex in *datesac*.

To compute the month span separately for each MRN (level 0 of the
MultiIndex), define a function, to be applied to each group:

```
def monthSpan(grp):
    dates = grp.index.get_level_values(1)
    return (dates.max().to_period('M') - dates.min().to_period('M')).n
```

Then add *MonthSpan* column to your *df*, running:

```
datesac['MonthSpan'] = datesac.groupby(level=0).transform(monthSpan);
```

The result is:

```
                    List  MonthSpan
MRN     ORDER_INST                 
1000031 2010-04-12     0         11
        2010-04-16     0         11
        2010-04-17     0         11
        2010-04-18     0         11
        2011-03-01     0         11
9017307 2018-11-27     0          7
        2019-02-04     0          7
        2019-04-25     0          7
        2019-05-14     0          7
        2019-06-09     0          7
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does not allow item assignments to a groupby object (a new column cannot be added to a groupby object) so the operation will have to be split. One solution is first calculate the month difference from the groupby object, merge the dataframes together, and then groupby again.

Create the first groupby object:

```
datesac = acdates.groupby(['MRN'])
```

Calculate the difference in months between each group and join to the original dataframe (or a new dataframe). This method requires numpy so import as necessary

```
import numpy as np    

acdates_new = pd.merge(
    left=acdates,
    right=((datesac['ORDER_INST'].max() - df_group['ORDER_INST'].min())/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).astype('int').rename("DATE_DIFF"),
    left_on='MRN',
    right_index=True
)
```

Regroup

```
datesac = acdates_new.groupby(['MRN'])
```